# Attempting to make POST request from one page on my site to another with PHP and Curl

Tags: php, post, curl

Hey all I have seen several questions on the topic here, but none of them have solved my problem. I have a script on my site which I want to use to generate several different types of emails to my users. I wanted a way to be able to create template files for the different emails which accept $_POST variables to fill in relevant information, and to simply make a post request to these templates and get back the response to place as the body of the email. I am attempting to write a function which would accept the location of the template file (either relative or absolute would work, but I would prefer relative honestly), and an array of parameters that I would like to send to the template via post. So far I have had no luck. Here is my code so far:

```
private function post_request($url, $data) {
    $output = array();
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    if ($result) {
        $output['status'] = "ok";
        $output['content'] = $result;
    } else {
        $output['status'] = "failure";
        $output['error'] = curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;
}
```

I have been getting the error "couldn't connect to host" from curl, but after outputting my url to an error log I have been able to verify that copying and pasting the URL into firefox results in seeing the page correctly.

Any ideas? I am not married to the idea of using curl, so if there is a better option I would be more than happy to use it instead. Thanks for the help all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the issue ended up being a server configuration error. The server was timing out while attempting to contact the file because it was hitting the wrong DNS server. Fixing that solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use file_get_contents() for this, so long as your host has not prevented it from accessing remote locations (and the $url script is not looking exclusively for POST data).

```
private function post_request($url, $data) {
    $output = array();

    $url_with_data = '';
    foreach ( $data as $k=>$v ){ // Loop through data and create request string
        $url_with_data .= '&' . $k . '=' . $v;
    }

    // Remove first ampersand and encode the data
    $url_with_data = urlencode( substr( $url_with_data, 1 ) );

    // Request file
    // Format will be http://url.com?var1=data&var2=data&var3=data
    $result = file_get_contents( $url . '?' . $url_with_data );

    if ($result) {
        $output['status'] = "ok";
        $output['content'] = $result;
    } else {
        $output['status'] = "failure";
        $output['error'] = 'Could not open remote file';
    }
    return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option: You say that both files reside on the same server.  If that is the case, you could simply require() the template builder.

```
private function post_request($url, $data) {
    $output = array();

    @require_once('./path/to/template_builder.php');

    if ($result) {
        $output['status'] = "ok";
        $output['content'] = $result;
    } else {
        $output['status'] = "failure";
        $output['error'] = 'Could not open remote file';
    }
    return $output;
}
```

Then in template_builder.php:

```
<?php

unset( $result );

if ( is_array( $data ) ){
    // Parse $data ...
    $result = $email_template;
}
```